# Retreving the text from the Dynamic Text boxes

Tags: asp.net

I am struggling with the below from last two days.Please help me.

I have .aspx page like this

```
<div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="pchStep4Adult" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder/>
<asp:button runt="server" text="next" onserverclick="ProceedNext"/>
</div>
```

then i have .aspx.cs code like this:

here i have a dynamic text box here and i want the text in that text box.
text boxes will be added dynamically and No of text boxes will change dynamically. Any no of Text boxes are created.

```
public partial class pages_travelersDetail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {                       
      TextBox tb= new TextBox();
      tb.ID = "tb" + i;   
      pchStep4Adult.Controls.Add(tb);           
   } 
}

//Here i want the text box value in a string.
protected void ProceedNext(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Here i want the text box value in a string.
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only one TextBox:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)pchStep4Adult.FindControl("tb1");
```

If your example was simplified and you actually have multiple TextBoxes, you could loop the PlaceHolder's ControlCollection to get all TextBoxes.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in pchStep4Adult.Controls){
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrl;
}
```